# Comodo Firewall blocks Eclipse Juno with Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, firewall

I have just downloaded the newest Eclipse (Juno) bundle with Andorid SDK.
Everytime I start the Eclipse the Comodo firewall pops up with message eclipse is trying to write at a protected area. I allow it and click the checkbox *Save the answer*. But it continues to pop up.

The message is similar to this:

`eclipse.exe is unknown and is trying to write c:\Users\XXX\Documents\android eclipse\eclipse\writtableArea5710289701803779300.dll ..."`

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Try running Eclipse as administrator?

Comment: already tried, but it's the same

Comment: Honestly, I'd just shut down the firewall and uninstall it if it can't handle exception rules properly.

Comment: 1. After eclipse runs the android SDK Manager wont open. Then I tried to run the Android SDK Manager over the cmd. It started but it showed Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
2. I shut down the firewall:
2.1 at the Android SDK Manager (run over cmd) comes the same message
2.2 eclipse wont start, it shows the eclipse "loading-screen" but it lasts too long.

Comment: I have read everything on the internet about the problem with running the android sdk manager properly. Nothing worked for me :-(
The worst that can happen to a developer when he tries to learn a new technology, is to have unavoidable problems with the installing of that technology :-(

Comment: If you are behind a router, try setting a static IP, and set the DNS servers to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Comment: I uninstalled comodo firewall and it solved all my problems